# how to choose random x,y coordinates of a polygon

Tags: javascript, coordinates, draw, polygon

I have a shape, a polygon. I have the x,y coordinates of the edges of this polygon.

I'd like to draw 50 circles of 10 pixel radius randomly in this shape.

How do I randomly choose a position in my polygon?

I'm doing this in canvas with javascript, but I don't need any actual code. Maybe some math equations or some direction would be enough

Comment: have you attempted anything?

Comment: you draw a 5px smaller polygon inside the first, and find the min/max x/y which are your random ranges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd get the whole area of the polygon , apply a rand function on it and draw the circles, if you need to avoid intersection you could create a 'collision' function. Perhaps this helps:

Set: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29
Calculating the area of a polygon: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon

Comment: thanks will take a look and see if I have follow up questions